# WebExtensions BrowserAction popup has fixed height in Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

The extension source code is at https://github.com/n8chz/prostetnic-chrome

It works on both Chromium and Firefox, but on Firefox the popup has fixed dimensions, so instead of having the popup grow as the script adds content to the popup, a vertical scrollbar appears, allowing me to view the content, but it's a bit of a speed bump that I'd be happier without.  Apparently [auto-resizing is a built-in feature of BrowserAction popups in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups).

The BrowserAction is declared in manifest.json as follows:

```
"browser_action": {
 "default_icon": {
  "19": "search19.png",
  "38": "search.png"
 },
 "default_title": "Search for words in previous highlights",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
```

Are there perhaps any hidden instantiation options other than the ones in the documentation?

One thing that helps (but produces a different effect from in Chrome) is adding `style="height: 600px"` to the popup's `<html>` element.  Anything 601px or larger results in a popup with a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Yes, in Firefox, popups are not are not auto-resized to fit your contents. Your "Question" only has declarative statements. Please tell us what your actual question is.

Comment: Using JavaScript, you could apply either different `style` attributes, or a different `class` based on if you are running under Chrome or Firefox.  Alternately, when running in Firefox, you can use JavaScript to resize the panel to your content, resize your content to the panel, or show/hide the scrollbars.

Comment: What I ended up doing is `<html style="height: 600px;">` in the popup.  Setting height to 601px causes vertical scrollbars to appear.  Growing the content inside the popup to more than 600px also causes scrollbars to appear.  It seems Mozilla engineered browser action popups to have customizable height, up to a hard maximum of 600px.

Comment: Yes, there is a likely a size limit as in Chrome. From the bug record linked in the [selected answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39476226/774575): "*In chrome the popup window dynamically changes (grows / shrinks) to suit changes to the content up to a maximum size of 800 x 600 px*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no hidden options other than what is in the docs.  This is a known bug which can be tracked at following site.  Doesn't work in FF50.0a2 yet.

Bug 1215025 - Popup size does not respond to content change. 
Target Milestone:   mozilla50
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215025